# How to return every nth row from dataset using postgresql to control a Highcharts data series

Tags: postgresql, highcharts

I am generating a data series for **Highcharts** using a dataset collected from a **postgres** db for 1 week, where there are datetime points every 15 secs. My current sql statement returns an array containing 40,320 arrays ([timestamp, int, string]). I want to reduce the amount of elements in the dataset to 1 row for every 240 rows.  I presume there is a way to handle this in Highcharts, but I have not found it after a good amount of research.

How can I do this in postgresql?

Currently, my initial dataset is collected using the sql statement below:

`SELECT timestamp, interest, yield FROM abc.public.table WHERE symbol='XTC' AND timestamp BETWEEN '2021-06-04 14:51:27.5127' AND '2021-06-11 14:51:27.5127' ORDER BY timestamp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() to enumerate your rows in a subquery (or CTE), and then `WHERE (rownum%240)=0`. An example using a CTE:

```
with
original_query as (
SELECT timestamp, interest, yield FROM abc.public.table WHERE symbol='XTC' AND timestamp BETWEEN '2021-06-04 14:51:27.5127' AND '2021-06-11 14:51:27.5127' ORDER BY timestamp
),
numbered as (
select row_number() over () as rownum, oq from original_query oq
),
sampled as (
select (oq).* from numbered where (rownum%240)=0
)
select * from sampled;
```